# Regex to match all words containing a question mark

Tags: regex, match

I need some help writing a regex that will match all words in a sql dump that contain a ? within the word somewhere... words can be on the same line and ideally I'll get a full list of these words so I can count the instances.

Sample

```
test
test??test
test?test  word ss?dd ?dddd
term_exists??   term_exists??
test
test?test
aaa?  aaaa???
```

I should see a list as follows

```
test??test
test?test
ss?dd
?dddd
term_exists??
term_exists??
test?test
aaa?
aaaa???
```

Basically all words that have a ? in them.

Any help would be great.. been banging my head on this for hours.

Comment: Are you running this pattern in an ide? or do we need to cater to a particular coding language?

Comment: What tool are you using? Notepad++? You say "banging my head for hours" - what have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

`.*?([a-z_]*\?+[a-z_]*).*?`

Replace with `\1` (or `$1` depending on the language you're using).

In action: https://regex101.com/r/Kr776J/1

For best results, enable "single line" mode if possible (Add `(?s)` to your pattern or use your language's options to turn the flag on).

Answer (score 0):

Given your input string, this will accurately match all of your desired substrings:

```
\w*\?[^\s]*
```

or more literally: `[a-z_]*\?[^\s]*`

or most literally: `[a-z_]*\?[a-z?]*`

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/RMT57z/2) (all just 90 steps)
CAustin's takes 159 steps.